# Updating tables using SQLAlchemy failing

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I have a connection to SQL Server with:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

server = 'server'
database = 'db'
driver = 'driver'
database_con = f'mssql://@{server}/{database}?driver={driver}'

engine = create_engine(database_con)
con = engine.connect()
```

I want to test inserting a data record, so create a df and run it with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':['test'], 'column2':[234],  'column3':[234.56]})
df.to_sql(
            name='A_table',
            con=con,
            if_exists="append",
            index=False
        )
```

This runs ok, verified by reading and viewing the table wtih:

```
query = 'select * from A_table'
data = pd.read_sql_query(query, con)
data
```

[image]

My issue arises when my colleague tries to view the data in SQL Server.

Running `select * from A_table` produces no result, after computing for >10min (it is only 3 rows and 3 columns)

Is there something I am missing. Does the update need to be committed to the server, or is there another way to ensure that when my colleague views the table they can see it without waiting for a long time.

Comment: Sounds like it's a open transaction. Does it work if you add (nolock) after the table name

Comment: Also you can run: dbcc opentran

Comment: It will display info about transactions

Comment: @siggemannen adding `with (nolock)` works. How does the data added become committed?

Comment: Read: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/future.html#sqlalchemy.future.Connection

Comment: Try using `con=engine` in your `to_sql()` call.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks. added `con.commit()` and it worked ok

Comment: Cool.  I added this as an answer.  You should accept it so other people can find the solution.

Comment: I must say it's such a bad default though. But what' strange is that after your python code was finished, shouldn't the transaction been rolled back due to python runtime exiting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The [Connection] object features “autobegin” behavior, such that any call to Connection.execute() will unconditionally start a transaction which can be controlled using the above mentioned Connection.commit() and Connection.rollback() methods.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/future.html#sqlalchemy.future.Connection

So run `con.commit()` to commit the changes.